# How do I share code via class structure in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am writing for the Qt framework and I want to create a QWidget. QWidget exposes some interfaces such as mousePressEvent and mouseReleaseEvent. I want to extend this class to allow mouseClickEvent and mouseDoubleClickEvent. Normally, you would think to extend QWidget and implement those functions. The problem is that there are other classes (QPushButton for example) provided as part of the library which extend QWidget. Therefore, how do I get that added functionality into those classes without having to extend each one and copy the code?

```
class ClickHandeler : public QWidget {
    virtual void mouseClickEvent();
    virtual void mouseDoubleClickEvent();

    int clickCount; //initialized to 0;

    void mouseReleaseEvent(QEvent *event){
        clickCount++;
        QTimer::singleShot(500, this, SLOT(checkClick()));
    }

    void checkClick(){
        if (clickCount == 2){
            this->mouseDoubleClickEvent();
            clickCount = clickCount-2;
        } else {
            this->mouseDoubleEvent()
            clickCount--;
        }
    }
}

// QPushButton inherits QWidget too! Yikes!
class MyPushButton : public QPushButton, public ClickHandeler {
    void mouseClickEvent(){
        alert("i have been clicked");
    }

    void mouseDoubleClickEvent(){
        alert("i have been double clicked");
    }
}
```

I want something like MyPushButton, but I am worried that the function overriding will not work as expected.

Im sorry if this question is obvious to people, but I do not know what the terminology is. I have googled interfaces for c++ and I get abstract interfaces (which doesnt properly solve this problem). If I'm just being stupid and need to know a better term for google, let me know in the comments and Ill remove the question.

Comment: You can derive other class from this using inheritance.

Comment: @user1929959 yea, thats what I noted, but the problem is that I dont want to have to copy the code for each new extended class thats ridiculously unmaintainable

Comment: In this case just override methods in other trivial manner.

Comment: @user1929959 huh? how would I override the method in a way that doesnt cause me to replicate the code everywhere? What do I override (I am trying to make a new function)?

Comment: Google "multiple inheritance" and "mixin". I am not sure these concepts will be easy to apply in your specific case, but it should be possible.

Comment: If you want to override the methods from QPushButton you should inherit from that class, not from QWidget (or probably even better -  depending on what you want - inherit from QAbstractButton)

Comment: @n.m. thanks! will do that

Comment: @Corijn yes, but I dont want to copy the code for the click handeling for every class I want to extend from, that makes it difficult to maintain. I want to do something like what I wrote in the updated question.

Comment: then you should call the method from the base class before or after your implementation. F.i. if you override a method `f` from class `A` in your subclass `B`, then you can write A::f() to call the corresponding function from the base class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to extend the QWidget and call the QWidget same functions.
For example:

```
class QWidget {
public:
    void mouseClickEvent();
};

class QPushButton {
public:
    void mouseClickEvent();
};

class MyWidget : public QWidget, public QPushButton {
public:
    void mouseClickEvent()
    {
        //base::mouseClickEvent();// ambiguous
        QWidget::mouseClickEvent();
        QPushButton::mouseClickEvent();
        /* Do your own code here */
    }
};
```

Comment: QPushButton is already inherited from QWidget, so this does not really make sense. You would have the diamond of death problem here.